# Expose AMD module globally when not in a RequireJS environment

Tags: javascript, browser, requirejs, amd

I am attempting to convert a classic JavaScript "class" into an AMD module.  However, I also need to keep exporting the class into the global namespace because some legacy code needs it. I've tried `this`, however, the global object is not created. What am I doing wrong?

```
define('VisitorManager', function () {

    var VisitorManager = function () {

        "use strict";

        // ...
    };


    VisitorManager.prototype.hasExistingChat = function () {
        // ...
    };


    //expose globally
    this.VisitorManager = VisitorManager;

    //return AMD module
    return VisitorManager;

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expose your module globally, you need to register it in the global object.

In the browser the global object is `window`:

```
window.VisitorManager = VisitorManager;
```

In a Node.js environment the global object is called `GLOBAL`:

```
GLOBAL.VisitorManager = VisitorManager;
```

To use the class in both a legacy environment and with RequireJS, you can use this trick:

```
(function() {

    var module = function() {

        var VisitorManager = function() {
            "use strict";

            // ...
        };

        // Return the class as an AMD module.
        return VisitorManager;
    };

    if (typeof define === "function" && typeof require === "function") {
        // If we are in a RequireJS environment, register the module.
        define('VisitorManager', module);
    } else {
        // Otherwise, register it globally.
        // This registers the class itself:
        window.VisitorManager = module();

        // If you want to great a global *instance* of the class, use this:
        // window.VisitorManager = new (module())();
    }

})();
```

Comment: I changed my code to include `window.VisitorManager = VisitorManager;` however the VisitorManager class is still not exposed globally. It appears the code in the module is not even executed.

Comment: @StevenMusumeche what environment are you developing for? Is it the browser? Is your .js file with this code included as a `<script src="..." />` in the page that you are loading?

Comment: Browser environment.  No, it is brought in my require.js.  I guess for the legacy code to use the global object, it needs to also be included as a <script> tag?

Comment: Is it by chance lazy-loaded?

Comment: The issue is that I need to be able to include this file in an environment without require.js.  Currently, in the legacy environment I get Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined

Comment: Yes, it is lazy loaded in the new environment.

Comment: @StevenMusumeche I have edited the answer. Try what I suggested.

Comment: @StevenMusumeche I just modified it a bit - changed `module()` to `new (module())()` so that the globally registered manager is an instance instead of the class. Check if this is what you need.

Comment: Thanks! When attempting to use the global version, I get this error: TypeError: VisitorManager is not a function. However, this does: window.VisitorManager = new module();

Comment: @StevenMusumeche I think I understand how you're using it. I have updated the code in my answer.